# codebehind file visual 2010 and 2013

Tags: object, master-pages

i have reccently installed Visual studio 2013 from 2010 . Now i can't find Codebehind file.

Or im kinda unsure if i can, and it just got a new design compared to 2010

```
Public Class WebForm3
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

But in 2010 it looked totally difference like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0opti.jpg

I really hope someone can help me. Since i have a homepage that im supposed to have done until the weekend, got everything ready to go, just need the backend coding :)

Comment: Right-click on the Form.vb file in the Project Explorer, and click View Code.

Comment: Cant find the Project explorer, i can only see Solution Explorer, im new to visual studio 2013 . Everything was easily found in Visual studio 2010. Really hope you can help further.

Answer (score 0):

Had to recreate the site, and make it a webform, instead of project . Fixed the problem.